# Группировка и запись каждой группы в отдельный Excel лист

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть исходная таблица, в ней несколько столбцов. Нужно из одного из столбцов выбрать одно из значений , и дальше посчитать сумму по другим столбцам, после этого сохранить в эксель, а лист назвать по имени того значения.
Пример:

```
Фирма   Дебет   Кредит
А   10  20
Б   20  20
В   20  10
Г   30  30
А   40  10
А   50  20
В   60  10
Г   40  30
А   10  30
```

Допустим берем фирму А, на выходе должно получить что-то типо этого

```
Фирма   Дебет   Кредит
А   10  20
А   40  10
А   50  20
А   10  30
    280 180
```

И это нужно сохранить в файл эксель, а лист назвать по названию фирмы , т.е. "А".
Предполагается , что в файле будет N листов в соответствии с N фирмами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы делал это так:

```
def add_total(df, grp_col='Фирма'):
    return (df.append(df.groupby(grp_col)
                        .sum()
                        .reset_index(drop=True),
                      sort=False)
              .fillna(''))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('d:/temp/result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for g, x in df.groupby('Фирма'):
    (add_total(x, grp_col='Фирма')
     .to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g, index=False))

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо, на данном примере все хорошо работает. Однако где в данном коде указание на тот столбец , который будет суммироваться? Просто в моем файле может быть до 15 столбцов, и нужно только 13 и 14 суммировать например. Как мне выбрать именно нужные столбцы?

Comment: @Max, суммироваться будут все столбцы, кроме того, по которому идёт группировка

Comment: @Max, именно поэтому так важно приводить __воспроизводимые__ примеры данных. В итоге и вы и я потратили свое время впустую... :(

Comment: Попробовал на своих данных, выдает ошибку дибликата имени листа
DuplicateWorksheetName: Sheetname ' xxx', with case ignored, is already in use.

Comment: @Max, попробуйте на тех данных, которые вы привели в вопросе

Comment: Хорошо, задам отдельный вопрос тогда)

Comment: @Max, [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: @Max, кстати мне кажется вы получили исчерпывающий ответ для сформулированного вами вопроса) ;-)

Comment: Нет, возникает ошибка, может потому что в названии фирм есть кавычки? не могу точно сказать)

Comment: Данный вопрос решен, благодарю!