# Группировка и запись каждой группы в отдельный Excel лист с нормализацией столбца группировки

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть исходная таблица, в ней несколько столбцов. Нужно из одного из столбцов выбрать одно из значений , и дальше посчитать сумму по другим столбцам, после этого сохранить в эксель, а лист назвать по имени того значения.
Пример:

```
         Дата  Номер Банк Фирма       БИК  Лицевой_счет  Дебет  Кредит Назначение
0  10.01.2018      5   СБ   "А"    456045        420265    100     200     оплата
1  10.02.2018      6   СБ   "А"      2132          4006    100     300     оплата
2  10.03.2018      4   СБ   "А"    123132        404540    500       0     оплата
3  10.04.2018      8  ССБ     В    564564           460    200     200      залог
4  10.05.2018      8   АБ     Б  12312323        203120    200     100      залог
5  10.06.2018      9   АБ     Г   1312123        231020    300     300     кредит
6  10.07.2018      8   АБ   "А"    211231          3103    150     100     кредит
7  10.08.2018      7   АБ     Д    231123          3123    120     100     кредит
8  10.09.2018      0   РТ     В      3233         30303    120     200      аванс
```

Допустим берем фирму А и считаем суммы только по некоторым столбцам (в данном примере "Дебет" и "Кредит" ) . На выходе должно получить что-то типо этого:

```
Дата    Номер   Банк    Фирма   БИК Лицевой счет    Дебет   Кредит  Назначение
10.01.2018  5   СБ  "А" 456045  420265  100 200 оплата
10.02.2018  6   СБ  "А" 2132    4006    100 300 оплата
10.03.2018  4   СБ  "А" 123132  404540  500 0   оплата
10.07.2018  8   АБ  "А" 211231  3103    150 100 кредит
                        1550    1200
```

И это нужно сохранить в файл эксель, а лист назвать по названию фирмы , т.е. "А".
Предполагается , что в файле будет N листов в соответствии с N фирмами.

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема с существующим листом в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909792) возникает в том случае если у вас встречаются названия фирмы различающиеся только регистром. Например `"A"` и `"a"` - Excel не различает регистр в имени листов - отсюда ваша ошибка

Comment: И каким образом ее можно решить?

Comment: Например привести все названия к одному регистру...

Comment: Так, а можно решить по-другому? Если я нахожу уникальные значения через value_counts() , и тело цикла сделать из этих значений?

Comment: Это ничего не изменит - `value_counts()` вернет и `"A"` и `"a"`. А какой смысл сохранять данные по фирме `"Рога и Копыта"` отдельно от фирмы `"Рога и копыта"` ?

Comment: Тогда может какой-то код может решить эту проблему? или такого еще не придумали? Когда 6000 строк например, как-то не очень хочется вручную искать такие ошибки

Comment: Придумайте как нормализовать имя фирмы! Я вам предложил вариант с приведением к единому регистру (например к верхнему) - это делается одной командой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86073/discussion-between-max-and-maxu).

Comment: Завтра попробую набросать вариант о котором вы спрашивали...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментариев выяснилось, что у автора вопроса существуют наименования фирм отличающиеся только регистром (например: `"Рога и Копыта"` и `"рога и копыта"`). В этом случае Pandas при группировке по наименованию фирмы будет рассматривать это как две разных группы строк. При записи групп в Excel файл возникает конфликт, т.к. Excel не позволяет создавать листы с одинаковыми именами.

NOTE: *Причём при сравнении имён листов регистр не учитывается*.

Чтобы обойти эту проблему можно нормализовать имена фирм при группировке. В результате в Excel файл попадают неизмененные (как есть) имена фирм, а в качестве имени Excel листа будет использоваться нормализованный вариант.

```
def normalize_name(col, maxlen=30):
    return col.str.upper().str[:maxlen]

def add_total(df, grp_col='Фирма', agg_cols=None, agg_func='sum'):
    if agg_cols is None:
        agg_cols = df.columns.drop(grp_col)
    return (df.append(df.groupby(grp_col)
                        [agg_cols]
                        .agg(agg_func)
                        .reset_index(drop=True),
                      sort=False)
              .fillna(''))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('d:/temp/result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for g, x in df.groupby(normalize_name(df['Фирма'])):
    (add_total(x, grp_col=normalize_name(df['Фирма']),
               agg_cols=['Дебет','Кредит'])
     .to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g, index=False))

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DataFrame для воспроизведения:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
         Дата  Номер Банк                                  Фирма       БИК  Лицевой_счет  Дебет  Кредит Назначение
0  10.01.2018      5   СБ  AAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    456045        420265    100     200     оплата
1  10.02.2018      6   СБ  AaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      2132          4006    100     300     оплата
2  10.03.2018      4   СБ  aAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    123132        404540    500       0     оплата
3  10.04.2018      8  ССБ                                      В    564564           460    200     200      залог
4  10.05.2018      8   АБ                                      Б  12312323        203120    200     100      залог
5  10.06.2018      9   АБ                                      Г   1312123        231020    300     300     кредит
6  10.07.2018      8   АБ  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    211231          3103    150     100     кредит
7  10.08.2018      7   АБ                                      Д    231123          3123    120     100     кредит
8  10.09.2018      0   РТ                                      В      3233         30303    120     200      аванс
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def add_total(df, grp_col='Фирма', agg_cols=None, agg_func='sum'):
    if agg_cols is None:
        agg_cols = df.columns.drop(grp_col)
    return (df.append(df.groupby(grp_col)
                        [agg_cols]
                        .agg(agg_func)
                        .reset_index(drop=True),
                      sort=False)
              .fillna(''))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('d:/temp/result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for g, x in df.groupby('Фирма'):
    (add_total(x, grp_col='Фирма', agg_cols=['Дебет','Кредит'])
     .to_excel(writer, sheet_name=g, index=False))

writer.save()
writer.close()
```